# Account created with web3 does not get listed

Tags: web3js, accounts

I am learning ethereum and I have setup a private node with geth. And have a simple client written to create account (web3 1.0 beta34) and list.
While the account creation is successful, but it does not get listed,

### code for account creation

```
var web3I    = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var accountI        = new Accounts(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var createAccount   = async () => {

    var {address, privateKey, signTransaction, sign} = await accountI.create();    
    var password    = "password";
    var keyStore    =   accountI.encrypt(privateKey, password);

};
```

### code for account listing

```
var getAccounts   = async () => {

    var accounts = await web3I.eth.getAccounts();    
    console.log("accounts address    ", accounts);    

};

getAccounts();
```

Q: Why does the account does not get listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think accounts.create just creates a new account object. You probably want to use [web3.eth.personal.newAccount](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount) instead. The following code works for me:

```
var web3I = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var createAccount = async () => {
    var {address, privateKey, signTransaction, sign} = await web3I.eth.personal.newAccount('password');    
};
createAccount();

var getAccounts = async () => {
    var accounts = await web3I.eth.getAccounts();    
    console.log("accounts address    ", accounts);    
};
getAccounts();
```

Comment: Thanks. This did not completely solve the issue. I had to add this to my geth node '--rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,account' startup arguments and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked by using web3.eth.personal.newAccount and adding --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,account" to my geth node startup agruments.

Comment: Be careful. Exposing personal over RPC could be vulnerable.

Comment: what is the correct way of doing this if i am to make my node public?

Comment: Using IPC connection is best possible approach as of now.

Comment: how is IPC more secure than RPC? you still mention --port for ipc. Is it not possible to have a SSL with RPC with geth ?